# How to develop with local podspec project

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podspec

ios noob here.
I have a react-native app and I wrote a native module (private).

now I want to use it.
in my app's podfile I've defined the module to be taken from `node_modules`, but in the module's podspec file I need to define `source` so I've wrote : `s.source = {:path => "./ios"}`.

Apparently this is not supported in cocoapods for a long time.
this fails with `Unsupported download strategy '{:path=>"./ios"}'.`

Any help for how can I make this work will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
s.source = { :git => 'file:///Users/MyName/path' }
My pod version is 1.7.4

Comment: doesn't work for me. I'm getting : `does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [this answer under Local Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398989/4311268) I describe how you can locate your file. At the early part, I also shared how we can create the podfile. Hope it helps