# React/RCTDefines.h' file not found (RN0.61)

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Performed RN upgrade from RN0.60 to RN0.61. Build failed with iOS, due to the following issue:

```
/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:10:9: 'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found
```

I am aware of this [breaking changes](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/). (React.xcodeproj is deprecated)

Try a few things

1. npx react-native-clean-project & re-setup project
2. remove Pods/ & pod install
3. ...running out of idea...

Here's how my podfile looks like.

```
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon'
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon'
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.9.0'
  pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'

  # FBSDK
  pod 'react-native-fbsdk', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk'

  pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'
  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'
  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'
  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my solution after spending a full day in digging the reason why,
.
.
.
.

## TLDR;

You need to add .podspec to podfile for whichever 3rd party/custom library that complain unable to find *React/{whatever.h}*

---

## 3rd party Libraries

If you are using a **3rd party library** (Yarn/NPM/etc)

1. Copy podspec from other 3rd party library (eg, RNDeviceInfo/etc..)
2. Create own podspec by replacing a few item (s.name, s.source) *I actually left others as default but you can modify as per your usage if you want*

```
s.name         = "NoSupportedLib"
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/react-native-community/NoSupportedLibName.git", :tag => "v#{s.version}" }
```

You might want to take care the following, because not all your dependency may store under the folder path `ios/**/your.m & your.h files`

```
s.source_files  = "ios/**/*.{h,m}"
```

3. Add new line to podfile
   `pod 'NoSupportedLib', :path => '../node_modules/NoSupportedLib'`
4. Pod install

## Local Dependencies

In the case where you have a **local dependency**, you should do the same as well (instead of adding the .a file into your Xcode's Linked Framework and Libraries.)

1. Follow the same steps as described on top
2. At step 2 where you declare the s.source & s.source_files, you shall do the following: *(Assumption you are create this custom.podspec at the same custom library path, you would otherwise need to modify the s.source path as your need)*

```
s.source            = { :http => 'file:' + __dir__ + '/' }
s.source_files  = "customLib/*.{h,m}"
```

3. Add new line to podfile

```
pod 'customLib', :path => '../localDependency/customLib'
```

### Sub-points

I tried adding **React** under my scheme as build target, apparently it does not help. I think for project that is >=RN0.60, we are meant to use [autolinking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#native-modules-are-now-autolinked) provided by ReactNative? Hence to keep our Xcode's Linked Framework and Libraries clean.
[image]

Comment: None of the above is working for react-native-local-auth. I created the .podspec inside the ../node_modules/reat-native-local-auth/RNLocalAuth.podspec as you suggested but I get error --->

No podspec found for `RNLocalAuth` in `../node_modules/react-native-local-auth/RNLocalAuth.podspec`

Comment: @Krishna check again your podspec name and location, you might have pointed it wrongly. Just my guess, you might want to call is this way in your podfile `pod 'RNLocalAuth', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-local-auth'`

Comment: Where to copy that podspec file? In main project or in the lib, in which I am getting error?

Comment: @NarendraSingh As I've mentioned above "Copy podspec from other 3rd party library (eg, RNDeviceInfo/etc..)". Simply just pick one Pod library from your project, look for their .podspec file and make modification to it.

Comment: but where to paste it? @TommyLeong

Comment: You really need to re-read my post. `You need to add .podspec to podfile for whichever 3rd party/custom library that complain unable to find React/{whatever.h}`

Comment: What if there is already a podspec defined in that lib? Do I need to modify that podspec then?

Comment: Right now, react-native-document-picker.podspec looks something like [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bHGhJd9NfV/). Do you mean, I should modify this existiing one? @TommyLeong

Comment: After trying whatever you suggested, I am getting this now ----  [!] There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `NoSupportedLib` in `Podfile`:

- NoSupportedLib (from `../node_modules/react-native-document-picker`)
- NoSupportedLib (from `../node_modules/NoSupportedLib`).

What to do for this one?

Comment: The modified react-native-document-picker.podspec looks like [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p6dKCHHpvN/)

Comment: @TommyLeong What do you suggest to change? The podspec is already in the format which you asked for. e.g. I am struggling with gesture-handler. And it has the following structure. And it same as what you ask to make. Confused! ------>.   
  s.name         = "RNGestureHandler"
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler", :tag => "#{s.version}" }

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue a while ago. It was fixed after: `product > scheme > edit scheme`, go to the build tab and add `react` as the first target.

[image]

Comment: Your answer looks valid but I still face the same output after adding `React` as my target. I also tried cleaning my build, pods and re-pod install again.

Comment: Can I check with you if you have any framework / .a files under Linked Framework and Libraries?

Comment: The only interesting framework I have there is `JavascriptScore.framework`.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for your help! I found my answer to solve the issue. Maybe you can take a look and provide your input too :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, I went into /node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h and changed #import <React/RCTDefines.h> into

```
#if __has_include("RCTDefines.h")
  #import "RCTDefines.h"
#else
 #import <React/RCTDefines.h>
#endif
```

ref below link

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26754#issuecomment-539550146

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Project navigator > Libraries > RNFetchBlob.xcodeproj
- Click on Build Settings and then the first item under "Targets"
- Scroll down to 'Search Paths' -> 'Header Search Paths'
- Make sure to have enable filter 'All'
- Add the following entry (click '+'): ${SRCROOT}/../../../ios/Pods/Headers
- Make sure to set it to recursive.
- Clean (cmd + shift + K) and re-build (cmd + B)

Solved [here](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/461#issuecomment-553355501)