# How can I link packages manually after upgrading the react-native version(Some third party packages not updated to podfile)

Tags: react-native

I am trying to upgrade the react-native version to 0.60. Here how can I link manually the package. (i.e) in androind if we add the packages in Build.gradle it will link manually for that particular package.

Can any one give solution how can we acheive this in iOS link.

Is the xcodeproj will support for the 0.60 and can we able to link manually.

I have tried in the latest version of react-native 0.61.5. But it not worked for me?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately from RN0.60 onwards, manual linking is not necessary as RN has a [mechanism of auto linking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md).

From my experience of upgrading to RN0.61, I've realized not all the library will be auto linked as expected. Reason being, the *.podspecs is not declared in your podfile. To perform this auto-linking, you need to include the 3rd party library's *.podspec within podfile. Hence during `pod install`, this *.podspec will tell the system where to grab the library, versions, etc.

I've previously [shared a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398989/4311268) related to RN0.61 and *.podpsec. Maybe you can read my solution and try with it, hope it helps!

Comment: If I unlink all  packages and run pod install it remove the third party library and it remove the pod from podfile.

Comment: During my upgrade, I did not unlink the package (bad example I guess) because I'm uncertain what is the correct steps to do. However, at xCode I have removed most of the library which was at LinkFramework&Library. I removed them based on the error message I received when I try to build, linker error shows up with the lib name.

Comment: For the latest need to unlink the manually linked packages. My question is can you able to see the .xcodeproj under Libraries or did ypou deleted it manually. Which version react-native did you upgrade

Comment: Remove most .xcodeproj under Libraries (yes, manually removed).

Comment: I did it manually but i am facing an error of RCTBridgeModule.h file not found

Comment: It's likely "React" not being found, it's a [breaking change] (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/#breaking-changes). Try to read the solution I shared in the answer