# React Native ios build error 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found with react-native-document-picker

Tags: ios, react-native, build-error, rctbridge

I am unable to build iOS App because of the issue - **'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found**

```
"react": "^16.13.1", 
"react-native": "^0.63.4", 
"react-native-document-picker": "^4.2.0"
```

iOS target -- 10.0

I already tried a few of the suggested solutions including
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43340802/1479511). Though, unable to follow the following step, as there was no React.xcodeproj file available

> Add react as a project dependecy
>
> Xcode Project Navigator -> drag React.xcodeproj from Libraries to root
> tree Build Phases Tab -> Target Dependencies -> + -> add React

Also tried
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52425997/1479511
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41664041/1479511

but still no luck yet :(

[image]

**UPDATE**

Tried following the steps suggested by @Muhammad Numan in the answer.

1. Check that I have React in my pods (pod 'React', :path =>
   '../node_modules/react-native/'). If not, add it.
2. Uninstall reinstall pods (pod deintegrate && pod clean && pod
   install in the ios folder, I believe the pod deintegrate command
   needs to be downloaded and isn't available by default)

[image: Error]

So, modified contents of `React.podspec` from

```
s.dependency "React-Core", version
  s.dependency "React-Core/DevSupport", version
  s.dependency "React-Core/RCTWebSocket", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTActionSheet", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTAnimation", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTBlob", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTImage", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTLinking", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTNetwork", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTSettings", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTText", version
  s.dependency "React-RCTVibration", version
```

to

```
s.dependency "React/Core", version
  s.dependency "React/Core/DevSupport", version
  s.dependency "React/Core/RCTWebSocket", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTActionSheet", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTAnimation", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTBlob", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTImage", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTLinking", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTNetwork", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTSettings", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTText", version
  s.dependency "React/RCTVibration", version
```

followed by the command `pod repo update`

Then, afterwards, getting this error

[image: Current Error]

Comment: Pls try removing pods folder and podfile.lock and try run pod update.

Comment: Getting same error with `pod update` too @HGK

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think you have the react missing thing, here's what I did.

1. Check that I have React in my pods (pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'). If not, add it.
2. Uninstall reinstall pods (pod deintegrate && pod clean && pod install in the ios folder,  I believe the pod deintegrate command needs to be downloaded and isn't available by default)
3. Go to scheme -> edit scheme -> build, delete the React(missing) using the 'minus' button. Click on 'add' or a 'plus' button. Find React (should be in the Pods category) and add it. Finally, make sure all boxes are ticked for React, and place it at the top of the list.

Here you go, I hope this helps. If however you do not have the React(missing), I have no idea how to solve this since i've never had this problem :/

Comment: I tried following the steps, that you have suggested. But now getting some other error with `pod install`. Please check the **UPDATE** in my post.

Comment: @NarendraSingh can you try this command `pod repo update`

Comment: remove `podfile.lock` and than try this

Comment: Still no luck :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227961/discussion-between-narendra-singh-and-muhammad-numan).

Comment: @NarendraSingh I have sent you to connect on LinkedIn but you never accepted. https://www.linkedin.com/in/nomi9995/

Comment: Ohh, okay, may be I missed it

Answer (score 0):

I have previously fixed this issue with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398989/4311268), which actually caused by React Native breaking changes (React.xcodeproj is deprecated).

Since the details answer is in the linked post, I do not re-post the entire solution here again but just a **TLDR** for you.

---

## TLDR;

You need to add .podspec to podfile for whichever 3rd party/custom library that complain unable to find React/{whatever.h}

Comment: @Narendra Singh, we are also using `react-native-document-picker` in project. However we are not on the latest version `4.3.0` instead we're using `2.1.0`. Im not sure whether there's any breaking change in between of these versions, but I suppose you can give it a try on 2.1.0 to see if thing works well for your end too.

Comment: After reducing it to 2.1.0. I started getting the other error, that is, `'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found`

Comment: Before trying to reduce to `2.1.0` have you tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373425/react-rctdefines-h-file-not-found-rn0-61/58398989#58398989) I shared in the link?

Comment: I tried that, but getting an error @TommyLeong